# Getting all Titles in an array Wordpress API

Tags: wordpress, api

I am using an appmaker and trying to get all titles of the posts on a website.

I get it to work to fetch a title of one item in the array. But I want it to show a list of all of the post

[this is what my integrationspage looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYYA8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get every post titles and nothing else, you should make a custom endpoint since the default /wp/v2/posts is paginated (wp/v2/posts?page=x)

It would be also more optimized than asking all data about posts and array_column the title